# Understanding conditional entropy intuitively $H[Y|X=x]$ vs $H[Y|X]$

Tags: entropy

I was trying to understand conditional entropy better. The part that was confusing me exactly was the difference between $H[Y|X=x]$ vs $H[Y|X]$.

$E[Y|X=x]$ makes some sense to me intuitively because its just the average unpredictability (i.e. information) of a random variable Y given that event x has happened (though not sure if there is more to it).

I do know that the definition of $H[Y|X]$ is:

$$H[Y|X] =  \sum p(x) H(Y|X =x) $$

But I was having trouble interpreting it and more importantly, understanding the exact difference between $H[Y|X=x]$ vs $H[Y|X]$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider two random variables $X$ and $Y$. If $X=1$ we know that $Y$ is also equal to one. So we do not have any *uncertainty* about $Y$ knowing that $X=1$. In this sense:
$$
H(Y|X=1)=0
$$
Now the question is: How uncertain are we about $Y$ if we know the realization of $X$? First of all, $H(Y|X=1)=0$ only tells us that we do not have any uncertainty about $Y$ only when we know that $X=1$. But for another $X$, for instance if we know that $X=2$, we may not know  exactly  about $Y$, which means that:
$$
H(Y|X=2)>0.
$$
Note that, we are looking for *a value* representing uncertainty of $Y$ if we know $X$. One option is to take the average of uncertainty that we have about $Y$ knowing each $X=x$, which gives us the notion of conditional entropy.

The notion represents *the average uncertainty* that we have of $Y$ knowing $X$. A good property of conditional entropy is that if we know $H(Y|X)=0$, then $Y=f(X)$ for a function $f$.

---

To see another interest behind the conditional entropy, suppose that $Y$ is an estimation of $X$ and we are interested in probability of error $P_e$. If for $Y=y$, we can estimate $X$ without error then $H(Y|Y=y)=0$. Interestingly, we can use [Fano's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano%27s_inequality) to find a lower bound on probability of error:
$$
H(X|Y)\leq P_e\log(\|\mathcal X\|)+1.
$$
And here the conditional entropy gives us an inner bound on the probability of error.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

It's intuitive to interpret $H(Y|X)$ by the chain rule:
$$H(Y|X)=H(X,Y)-H(X)$$

> Assume that the combined system determined by two random variables X
>   and Y has joint entropy $H(X,Y)$, that is, we need $H(X,Y)$ bits of
>   information on average to describe its exact state. Now if we first
>   learn the value of $X$, we have gained $H(X)$ bits of information.
>   Once $X$ is known, we only need $H(X,Y)-H(X)$ bits to describe the
>   state of the whole system.

And the difference can be also found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy):

> If $H(Y|X=x)$ is the entropy of the discrete random variable $Y$
>   conditioned on the discrete random variable $X$ taking a certain value
>   $x$, then $H(Y|X)$ is the result of **averaging $H(Y|X=x)$** over all
>   possible values $x$ that $X$ may take.

Answer (score 0):

There is a *beautiful* explanation of this in the [wikipedia page for conditional entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy) under **motivation**.
$$H(Y\mid X)=\sum_x p(x) H(Y\mid X=x)$$
That is, we want the weighted average.  Here's where it becomes interesting because
$$H(Y\mid X=x)=-\sum_y p(y\mid x)\log p(y\mid x)$$
With $p(y,x) = p(y\mid x)p(x)$ this gives us:
$$H(Y\mid X)=-\sum_{x,y} p(y,x)\log\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}$$
I kept thinking well why is it not just:
$$-\sum_{x,y}p(y\mid x)\log p(y\mid x)$$
Because it is the weighted sum, not the sum.

Answer (score -1):

There is some information since you don't know the value of $X$, so

$$ H[Y|X=x] \leq H[Y|X] = \sum p(X=x) H[Y|X=x] \leq H(X,Y)$$   Merely knowing that $X$ has taken some value, lowers the amount of information you learn from $Y$.

It is certainly lower than the joint entropy of $X$ and $Y$.

$$H(X,Y) = \sum p(x,y) \log p(x,y) $$

---

If this were conditional expectation you'd have the linearity of expectation.   Knowing that $X$ takes *some* value doesn't change your expection.

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y|X] =  \sum p(x) \mathbb{E}(Y|X =x) = \mathbb{E}[Y] $$

Comment: I think the expression $H(Y|X=x)\leq H(Y|X)$ is wrong. Because first of all $H(Y|X)\leq \max_x{H(Y|X=x)}$ which by accepting your statement means that $H(Y|X)= \max_x{H(Y|X=x)}$. This is simply false. Look at $X$ and $Y$ Gaussian and take $Y=X+Z$ where $Z$ is an independent Gaussian RV.

Comment: Also your statement about conditional expectation is wrong. $\mathbb E(Y|X)$ is not $\mathbb E(Y)$.