# find entropy of Markov chain

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, conditional-probability, information-theory, entropy

There is an information source on the information source alphabet $A = \{a, b, c\}$ represented by the state transition diagram below
[image: markov chain]

The $i$-th output from this information source is represented by random variable $X_i$. It is known that the user is now in state $s_1$. In this state, let $H (X_i \mid s_1)$ denote the entropy when observing the next symbol $X_i$, find the value of $H (X_i \mid s_1)$, entropy of this information source, Calculate $H (X_i\mid X_{i-1}) $ and $H (X_i)$ respectively. Assume $i$ is quite large.

How can I find $H(X_i|s1)?$ I know that  $H(X_i\mid s_1) = -\sum_{i} p\left(x_i, s_1\right)\cdot\log_b\!\left(p\left(x_i|s_1\right)\right) = -\sum_{i} p\left(x_i, s_1\right)\cdot\log_b\!\left(\frac{p\left(x_i, s_1\right)}{p\left(s_1\right)}\right)$
but I don't know $p(s_1).$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}0.25 & 0.75 & 0\\0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\0 & 0.7 & 0.3 \end{pmatrix}.$

from matrix I can know that $p(s_1|s_1)=0.25$, etc

but what is the probability of $s_1$?
and how can I calculate $H (X_i|X_{i-1})$?　is this stationary distribution too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that $H(X_i|s_1)$ is a succint way of writing $H(X_i|X_{i-1}=s_1)$. Then, recall that the entropy of a random variable conditioned on a particular value of another variable (different from the plain conditional entropy, if you are confused by this read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770709/understanding-conditional-entropy-intuitively-hyx-x-vs-hyx) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy)) is computed the same as the plain entropy, only replacing plain probabilities with conditional probabilities:

$$H(X_i \mid X_{i-1}=s_1)= - \sum_{X_i} P(X_i\mid X_{i-1}=s_1) \log P(X_i\mid X_{i-1}=s_1)   \tag1$$

Because the values of $P(X_i\mid X_{i-1}=s_1)$ are given by the first row of $A$, you don't need any extra data to compute this.

But you indeed need the stationary distribution to compute $H(X_i \mid X_{i-1})$:

$$ H(X_i \mid X_{i-1})= \sum_k P(X_{i-1}=s_k) \, H(X_i \mid X_{i-1}=s_k) \tag2$$